# How do you inherit StringBuilder in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, stringbuilder

I want to add my own member to the StringBuilder class, but when I go to create it IntelliSense doesn't bring it up.

```
public class myStringBuilder()
    Inherits System.Text.[StringBuilder should be here]
    ....
end class
```

Is it even possible? thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`StringBuilder` is `NotInheritable` (aka `sealed` in C#) so you cannot derive from it. You could try wrapping `StringBuilder` in your own class or consider using [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx) instead.

Comment: Does anyone know why it is sealed?

Comment: @oleks: Probably because it costs money to test and validate APIs and sealing it reduces this cost.

Answer (score 3):

No, [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) is a [NotInheritable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h278d2d4.aspx) class.  You could try wrapping a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) instance, but can't inherit from it.  You can also use [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx), if you're using .NET 3.5.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that was what I was going to have to do.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with, for those who are curious:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Module sbExtension
    <Extension()> _
    Public Sub AppendFormattedLine(ByVal oStr As System.Text.StringBuilder, _
                                   ByVal format As String, _
                                   ByVal arg0 As Object)
        oStr.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", String.Format(format, arg0), ControlChars.NewLine)
    End Sub
    <Extension()> _
    Public Sub AppendFormattedLine(ByVal oStr As System.Text.StringBuilder, _
                                   ByVal format As String, ByVal arg0 As Object, _
                                   ByVal arg1 As Object)
        oStr.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", String.Format(format, arg0, arg1), ControlChars.NewLine)
    End Sub
    <Extension()> _
    Public Sub AppendFormattedLine(ByVal oStr As System.Text.StringBuilder, _
                                   ByVal format As String, _
                                   ByVal arg0 As Object, _
                                   ByVal arg1 As Object, _
                                   ByVal arg2 As Object)
        oStr.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", String.Format(format, arg0, arg1, arg2), ControlChars.NewLine)
    End Sub
    <Extension()> _
   Public Sub AppendFormattedLine(ByVal oStr As System.Text.StringBuilder, _
                                  ByVal format As String, _
                                  ByVal ParamArray args() As Object)
        oStr.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", String.Format(format, args), ControlChars.NewLine)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I updated the code (and ported it to C#): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272534/how-do-i-port-an-extension-in-vb-net-to-c/1272544

Answer (score 1):

StringBuilder is a sealed class... so inheritance is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

StringBuilder is sealed.  You cannot inherit from it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an earlier version of .Net, you can write basically the same StringBuilderExtensions class and then explicitly call the static method instead.

With .Net 3.5:   `myStringBuilder.MyExtensionMethod(etc...);`

Pre- .Net 3.5:   `StringBuilderExtensions.MyExtensionMethod(myStringBuilder, etc...);`